# Inject jQuery into Puppeteer page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm trying to inject jQuery into my Puppeteer page because `document.querySelector` doesn't cut it for me:

```
async function inject_jquery(page){
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    var jq = document.createElement("script")
    jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(jq)
  })
  const watchDog = page.waitForFunction('window.jQuery !== undefined');
  await watchDog;
}
```

The result is it mostly times out. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: did you try `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq)` ?
Also, since you are setting `src`, listening to the `load` event of the script element and then returning might be more robust.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have used `page.addScriptTag` to inject `js` files.

```
...
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'})
...
```

[page.addScriptTag](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions) - documentation

Working example using `puppeteer: 0.12.0`

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer'
(async () => {
    const browser = await launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
    await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This also gives me: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise { <rejected> Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed. undefined

Comment: Nevermind, I needed to add a `await page.waitForNavigation()` before that part. This is the best solution.

Comment: You shouldn't need `waitForNavigation()` here, nor `networkidle` (I don't think `networkidle` is a [valid option](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.goforward/#remarks)--it should be `networkidle0` or `networkidle2`, BTW). Adding `console.log(await page.evaluate(() => $("h1:contains(Example)").text()));` after the `page.addScriptTag` call works for me.

Answer (score 25):

I am doing this:

```
await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' });
const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const $ = window.$; //otherwise the transpiler will rename it and won't work
  return $('h1 > span').text();
});
```

Answer (score 25):

For those looking to inject a local copy of jQuery:

`await page.addScriptTag({path: require.resolve('jquery')})`

Comment: im on ES6 and no 'require' :)

Comment: This works now: await page.addScriptTag({path: 'myScript.js'})

Comment: This does not work as almost all pages, have some kinda CSP enabled and so this will be blocked.

Answer (score 6):

Some sites won't allow you to inject a script tag, so you'll have to inject the contents of it before it'll allow you to do so. If that's the case you can use the `evaluate` method to grab the scripts contents from a CDN and inject them manually:

```
const jquery = await page.evaluate(() => window.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js').then((res) => res.text()));
await page.goto(YOUR_PAGE_HERE);
await page.evaluate(jquery);
```

This is used in scraping puppeteer's docs for [browserless here](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless/blob/master/scripts/get-meta.js#L52) (I'm the author of this tool) if you'd like to see an example in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
async function inject_jquery(page){
      await page.evaluate(() => {
        var jq = document.createElement("script")
        jq.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        return new Promise( (resolve) => {
            jq.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
                resolve();
            });
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
        });
      })
      const watchDog = page.waitForFunction('window.jQuery !== undefined');
      await watchDog;
    }
```

Comment: This gives me: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise { <rejected> Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed. undefined

Comment: Is your page object still valid when invoking `inject_jquery` ?. Can you sharing the invoking code ? Atleast for academic reasons, this answer might explain why your script was failing.
I believe the solution by nilobarp is more simpler

Comment: I don't think you need to `waitForFunction` to poll since you're already awaiting for the script to load. `.src` should be set after the load handler, though.

Answer (score 3):

**The best** solution found so far, URL insertion may not work due to browser origin policies, so we insert local file contents instead of URL.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const addJQueryToPage = async (page) => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'jquery-file-in-same-directory.min.js'), 'utf8');
    await page.addScriptTag({ content: file });
    await page.evaluate(_ => {
        $.noConflict();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To inject jQuery from CDN (inspired by @browserless answer above):

```
// go to page
await page.goto(url_str);
        
// inject jQuery
var jquery_ev_fn = await page.evaluate(function(){
    return window.fetch('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js').then(function(res){
        return res.text();
    });
});
await page.evaluate(jquery_ev_fn);
```

To inject local jQuery:

```
// get local jQuery and inject it
var jquery_code_str = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/local/jquery.js', 'utf8');

// go to page
await page.goto(url_str);
        
// inject jQuery
var jquery_ev_fn = await page.evaluate(function(code_str){
    return code_str;
}, jquery_code_str);
await page.evaluate(jquery_ev_fn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just publish my puppeteer jquery integration [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-jquery)

code sample:

```js
let browser = await launch({headless: true});
let pageOrg = await browser.newPage();
let page = pageExtand(pageOrg);
// append a <H1>
await page.jQuery('body').append(`<h1>Title</h1>`);
// get the H1 value
let title = await page.jQuery('h1').text();
// chain calls
let text = await page.jQuery('body button:last')
          .closest('div')
          .find('h3')
          .css('color', 'yellow')
          .parent()
          .find(':last')
          .text();
```

Not all jQuery function are mapped yet, so open issue if you need some more function (Each call need to be add by name and with the number of parameter they take).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to add jQuery to the page using [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js';
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
  });
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  await promise;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It becomes more easier to manage if you inject your script into the your html page header if you have got like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.min.js"></script>
```

and now you can easily call its function in your **page.evaluate(function(){ })**