# get TypeError: $ is not a function and I'm trying to scrape data

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I got TypeError: $ is not a function and I'm trying to scrape data  from a website using puppeteer and cheerio in nodejs

I'm trying to build a scraper app to collect  data from websites

error:

```
node:11668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: $ is not a function
    at checkPrice (file:///E:/vs%20work/scraper/index.js:26:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async monitor (file:///E:/vs%20work/scraper/index.js:44:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11668) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

code:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import $ from 'cheerio';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';



const url = 'https://www.amazon.eg/-/en/Sony-Bluetooth-Cancellation-Headphone-Microphone/dp/B08F4XTS93/'




async function configureBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    return page;
}

async function checkPrice(page) {
    await page.reload();
    let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    // console.log(html);
    
    $('#priceblock_ourprice', html ).each(()=>{
        let EGPPrice = $(this).text()
        console.log(EGPPrice);
    })
}



 async function monitor(){
    let page = await configureBrowser()
    await checkPrice(page)
}

monitor()
```

Comment: See: [Inject jQuery with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987516/inject-jquery-into-puppeteer-page) and [puppeteer-jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-jquery).

Comment: It seems `import $ from 'cheerio';` is a wrong way: see example in https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#loading

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [you probably don't need Cheerio if you're using Puppeteer](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer). Puppeteer already has selectors that work on the live site, so using Cheerio just means you're dumping a (probably) stale version of the already-parsed, live DOM into a facsimile of the browser's HTML parser. That makes no sense on 99% of use cases. I'd just use `await page.$eval("#priceblock_ourprice", el => el.textContent)` here and skip the potential bugs, extra syntax, confusion between which library I'm using, slowness and extra dependency and just use Puppeteer.

Second of all, if you *must* dump Puppeteer's HTML, use `await page.content()` rather than `await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);`.

Next, `import $ from "cheerio"` isn't correct. Cheerio exports a `cheerio` object which loads the HTML with `cheerio.load(html)`. This is the function that returns your jQuery simulator `$`. So the correct code flow should be:

```js
import cheerio from "cheerio";

const html = "<p>test</p>";
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("p").text());
```