# Undefined $ when scraping website with Playwright using ajax request

Tags: jquery, node.js, playwright

I wanted to scrape a website. I'm using nodejs with playwright as a scraper. I use ajax request with jQuery. I already installed the jquery via npm. Assuming that the url is a valid.Sometimes scraping is successful but, at some point, I got this error. How do I resolve it.

I did try looking for solution, but I could not find one that fit to my case.

```
//Start
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');
const $ = require('jquery');

test('Running webiste parser...', async ({ page }) => {
    try {
        await page.goto('https://www.testwebsite.com');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Test/DailyDataAsync',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                reject(error);
            },
        });
        });
    });
    
      
        if(Object.keys(data).length){
        console.log(data);
    }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
//End
```

Here the issue:

```
[chromium] › example.spec.js:5:1 › Running ngcp webiste parser...
page.evaluate: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:202:30), <anonymous>:3:9)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:202:30), <anonymous>:2:14)
    at UtilityScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:204:17)
    at UtilityScript.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)
    at C:\Work\NodeJs\scraper\tests\example.spec.js:9:35
  2 passed (2.7s)
```

Comment: try this `await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' });` before `page.evaluate(...)`

Comment: @DiegoD,

tried this and I got this error. By the way, im scraping a website that uses CloudFlare

Comment: [chromium] › example.spec.js:5:1 › Running ngcp webiste parser...
page.addScriptTag: Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' *.testwebsite.com*.cloudflare.com *.b-cdn.net fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com *.gstatic.com unsplash.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com *.googleapis.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.datatables.net *.google.com 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src'

Comment: since in that page you cannot inject jQuery from an external resource, your alternative approach could be to load it inline. So this could be a solution: `const jQueryCode = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
await page.addScriptTag({ content: jQueryCode });`  but it requires you to have `jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` locally. Be aware that it's different from `require('jquery')` as you used in your former example. Here we are loading js in the context of the page

Comment: You're importing jQuery into Node, not the browser. `evaluate` runs in the browser, not Node. Include jQuery as a script tag as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410535/6243352). BTW, jQuery is pretty old at this point and `fetch` is supported by any browser Puppeteer runs, easily replacing `$.ajax`. So you might not need it anyway.

Comment: I made some improvements in mycodes and running 50 test I did not encounter $ is not defined. However, i got an error sometimes. 

**await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'}); 
const $ = window.$; **

But i got this error:
page.addScriptTag: [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Using the other way:

await page.addScriptTag({path: 'node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js'})
const $ = window.$; 

ERROR:
frame.addScriptTag: [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-FKzHaEzhxRYdVVYcIkJN7SB2jGQPaASwQ21ExsMxsog='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.